# Java 8 to 11; exporting jar issue with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, executable-jar, java-11

I recently switched to using jdk11 for my game and suddenly when i export to a runnable jar, no dependencies that i put in the build.gradle file are present in the jar.
Switching back to jdk8 resolves this issue. How can I fix this? Also why does it work for 8 but not 11 when you export through eclipse?

My project is a gradle project and manually adding dependencies to the project settings as external jars seems to work but I’d rather not do this.

Currently using eclipse 2020-09 version

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/", "../client-core/assets/" ]

project.ext.mainClassName = "com.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../client-core/assets");

task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}

task debug(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
    debug = true
}

task dist(dependsOn: classes, type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}
    from files(project.assetsDir);
 
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}
// TODO. dist still generates a small jar with "build", and the full jar with "release".
// it should generate no jar unless called directly with release.

eclipse {
    project {
        name = "client-launcher"
        linkedResource name: 'assets', type: '2', location: 'PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/client-core/assets'
    }
}

task afterEclipseImport(description: "Post processing after project generation", group: "IDE") {
  doLast {
    def classpath = new XmlParser().parse(file(".classpath"))
    new Node(classpath, "classpathentry", [ kind: 'src', path: 'assets' ]);
    def writer = new FileWriter(file(".classpath"))
    def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer))
    printer.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
    printer.print(classpath)
  }
}
```

Comment: Add `jar { manifest {attributes "Main-Class": "your main class" } from {configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory()? it : zipTree(it) } }` in your build.gradle file and run clean/build. A jar would come up in \build\libs folder. That's your runnable jar.

Comment: I’ll try it but is there a reason why it works with jdk8 and not jdk11 when exporting from eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Try including equivalent of maven-assembly-plugin in your grade. The default packaging only packages the complied class files.

Comment: But why does it work for java 8 and not 11?